# Individual 401(k) and Contribution Limits

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, solo-401k

For an individual who was self-employed part of this year and contributed to an [Solo 401(k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_401(k)).  Now the individual is employed and covered under a standard 401(k).

Does the solo 401(k) contribution lower the 18K contribution limit to the 401(k)?

Comment: Just to clarify: the duplicate's (correct) answer is that yes, it does lower the limit: the limit is in total of all 401(k) plans.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple 401(k) plans, however the total annual contribution limit is still a total of $18k (in 2015).

As you anticipated in your question, if you defer 10K in one plan, for example, you may only contribute up to $8k in the second plan in order to stay under the $18k 2015 deferral limits.

[Here's an article with more details](http://budgeting.thenest.com/can-two-401k-plans-same-time-24237.html).

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as the answer in the linked duplicate?

Comment: wrote it before I knew it was a dup.

Comment: Ah, understood.